# Windows Authentication for IIS app in Azure VM

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, iis, windows-authentication

I have a legacy asp.net application that I have put on IIS in an Azure VM. This VM is domain joined to an Azure AD Tenant. This works fine for Windows Auth for one tenant but is it possible to set up trust between this tenant and another Azure ad tenant with ADFS to allow other organisations to authenticate with the app and/or other apps on the same VM?

How do I go about this? Or is the only option to change the code to work with  OpenID connect or another auth technology? If so, are there any code examples out there for vb.net to incorporate this?

I'm just a little confused about the best way to handle authentication to IIS but still keep windows auth working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure Active Directory Access Control Service to federate between the other identity provider and Azure AD. You need to register ADFS as an identity provider in ACS and also your application as a relying party and then update your code to authenticate against ACS.

Here are some links describing the solution

- [AD ACS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals-identity)
- [Federated Identity with ACS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446535.aspx)
- [Configure AD FS as an identity provider in ACS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185961.aspx)